# Php qr code generator works strange with utf-8 phrase

Tags: php, qr-code

I downloaded the library http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/ and wrote simplest code for it

```php
include('./phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
QRcode::png('иванов иван иванович 11111');
```

But resulted qr code contains only half of string

Resulted qr code - 'иванов иван ив';

url - [vologda-oblast.ru/coronavirus/qr/parampng.php](http://vologda-oblast.ru/coronavirus/qr/parampng.php)

What can be wrong?

Comment: you might not be using the right size for the picture, there should be an ECC param you can set, which determines the final size of the image which directly affects how much data you can store in it

Comment: It's not about picture size, doesn't matter how long or short is my phrase, effect is same or, sometimes, result consist of hieroglyphs

Comment: maybe you have to `urlencode()` the text first,  have you tried to use the embeded example on the documentation site? (it is on the bottom of the page), does that yield the same result?

Comment: Bitrix have recently updated their software to no longer rely on "mbstring.func_overload = 2", see https://idea.1c-bitrix.ru/remove-dependency-on-mbstring-settingsfuncoverload/?commentId=125264#125264 for more details.

Answer (score 2):

The "phpqrcode" library in your case encodes a number of characters instead of the number of bytes of a UTF-8 string. That’s why the string is truncated. If you QR-encode English-only text, the string will not be truncated. The truncation occurs only with Cyrillic characters since it takes 2 bytes to encode each Cyrillic character in UTF-8 rather than just a single byte for a Latin one.

Interestingly, the demo example of the library on the author’s page do encode Cyrillic characters correctly.

The truncation happens in your case because you are using the following options in your php.ini file:

```
mbstring.func_overload = 2
mbstring.internal_encoding = "UTF-8"
```

If you remove the `mbstring.func_overload` (deprecated since PHP 7.2.0) from `php.ini` or set it 0, the "phpqrcode" library will start working properly. Otherwise, the `strlen()` function used by the library will return number of characters rather than the number of bytes in a UTF8-ecoded octet string, while `str_split()`, another function used by the library, will always return the number of bytes since it is not affected by `mbstring.func_overload`. As a result, your QR-codes will contain truncated strings.

Since you are using the Bitrix Site Manager CMS, removing the `mbstring.func_overload` from `php.ini` may be problematic until you fully update Bitrix to 20.5.393 (released on September 2020) or later version. Earlier version did rely on this deprecated feature. You can find find more information about Bitrix reliance on this deprecated feature at https://idea.1c-bitrix.ru/remove-dependency-on-mbstring-settingsfuncoverload/ or https://idea.1c-bitrix.ru/?tag=4799

Since you cannot change `php.ini` configuration on run-time, you can try to configure your web server to have php options configure on a per-directory level. Failing that, you can fix the code of the "phpqrcode" library to work correctly, at least partially, in your case, to not rely on the `strlen()` function. To to that, edit the `qrencode.php` file the following way. First, replace the `$eightbit` constant of the `QREncode` class from `false` to `true`. Second, in the function `encodeString8bit`, replace

```
        $ret = $input->append(QR_MODE_8, strlen($string), str_split($string));
```

to

```
        $arr = str_split($string);
        $len = count($arr);
        $ret = $input->append(QR_MODE_8, $len, $arr);
```

Anyway, since the "phpqrcode" library does not currently support Extended Channel Interpretations (ECI) mode, you cannot reliably encode Cyrillic characters with the library. It uses the `8-bit string` mode of storing text in a QR code, which by default may only contain ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) characters unless the default character set is modified by a ECI entry. But the library cannot insert the ECI entry into a QR code to show that the text has UTF-8 encoding rather than ISO-8859-1. Some decoding applications will auto-detect the wrong charset and show the string correctly, while some (compliant) may not.

As a conclusion, since the "phpqrcode" does not currently support ECI, you cannot reliably encode Cyrillic characters with it, but you can at least make it not truncate the string as I have shown above.